# Reference for poisson equation

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, greens-function, poissons-equation

I don't know if this is ok to ask in stack exchange but I've been looking for a reference book to solutions of partial differential equations for some time. Can anyone tell me their favorite? I am currently looking for one that includes a table of the Green's functions to the Laplacian in arbitrary dimension. Thanks!

Comment: have a look at C. Evans "Partial Differential Equations", also "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations" by F. Lin and Q. Han is a fantastic set of lecture notes.

Comment: After you consulted one of the good books suggested above, you might be happy with the following suggestion. Its a very well written intoduction to pseudo differential operators. At least I never saw a better introduction for the very beginner: clear, not hiding details, meaningful exercises, historical details. No pde introduction, no greens functions, which you seek primarily for, but you can add a whole new level of understanding for elliptic equations with this very short(118 pages) book: "Elementary Introduction to the Theory of Pseudodifferential Operators" by Xavier Saint Raymond.